# Android close app when back button is pressed

Tags: android

Hi I made a modification in my app which is I want to close my app after clicking the back button. This might sound common right? but this is what exactly happens to my app. I have 3 screens: Start Page, Game Page and Score Page. after pressing the start button from the Start page it will start the Game Page Intent. After finishing the game the Game Page will then move the intent into Score Page and when the back button is pressed from the Score Page, the intent will be passed on the Start Page like this:

1. Start Page -> Game Page
2. Game Page -> Score Page
3. Score Page (when back button is pressed) -> Start Page

Now after I go back to the Start Page when I pressed the back button again instead of exiting the app it will just go back to the Score Page and again If I pressed the back button it will go to the Start Page again making an endless loop. I placed this code to my Start Page but it doesn't solve my problem:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Startup.this.finish();
}
```

Do I need to change the flow of my intents or there is a possible solution for this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you can just use the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when calling the Start page from the Score page.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class)
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 2):

just add this snippet on your game page

```
//just after your startActivity(scoreIntent)
this.finish();
```

this will finish the game activity before launching the score activity.
Now, when you want to end the score activity too, do not launch a new intent with start activity, but just end your score activity (this mean, leave the backpressed callback on its default.

this works because if you close game activity at its natural end, the second-topmost activity in your stack will be the start one. This allows you to just end the topmost activity (the score one) to retrieve the start page.

NOTE: this solution works only in your current workflow. if you add another page (example start-game-gameover-score) you need to replicate this behavior in every non-external activity (in the previous example, in game and gameover pages)

Comment: oh I see so that just means my activity doesn't end up instantly after I clicked the back button? Thanks for your answer, it's my first time adding an intent on my activity which is why I'm not quite familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

in StartPage when startActivity for Game Page do the following

```
  startActivity(intent);//intent for GamePage
  finish();
```

in Game Page when startActivity for Score Page do the following

```
  startActivity(intent);//intent for Score Page
  finish();
```

in Score Page when pressing BackButton do the following

```
startActivity(intent);//intent for StartPage
  finish();
```

Comment: this will cause StartPage activity to be destroyed and recreated (pointlessly) at every app loop.

Comment: if he wants to go to the StartPage from ScorePage

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you called new activity with new intent then write

```
finish();
```

after `startActivity()`.

Please check after write `finish()` when you called new activity.

One another option.
Write launchmode in your `manifest` file these activity called only one time

Manifest File -- > `<activity android:name="Main" android:launchMode="singleTask" />`

Comment: this one saved me man! thanks, i needed to avoid someone passing over the log in activity, when i was pressing the "Back button" it would take them to the main (logged-in) activity lol. Thanks!