# How to close application totally

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

Application is having 2 activities. I am using following code in each activity to close the application totally and free all resources when home button is pressed. But when i restart the app, it starts from the activity it left earlier.
How to achieve the objective.

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: finish() is enough for your need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: [Hope this helpful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11081342/940096)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close your application at your need. You can call `finish()` in every `Activity` when you navigate away from it. But then again, there is no guarantee that the OS will free up the resources immediately and close your `Activity`.

Never try to implement something like exiting your application. [Read this for a good discussion on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238).

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not close application totally. Let system itself decide.
2. Do not call `super.onDestroy()` in `onStop` method!
3. Use `finish()` for activity stoping.
4. You always have `System.exit()`

Comment: Why don't you like `System.exit`?

Comment: I had read somewhere that `System.exit()` shouldn't be suggested for Android apps.

Comment: **WHY** *Do not call super.onDestroy() in onStop method*?

Comment: Yea. Found it here : _System.exit() does not kill your app if you have more than one activity on the stack. What actually happens is that the process is killed and immediately restarted with one fewer activity on the stack._  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2632649/828625

Comment: @GAMA read about activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara Thanks a lot! I have used it in my projects, and it works all right(at least in DDMS I heven't seen my process any more). May be there was some changes? I have testsd on 2.3.3

Comment: I don't think there would have been any changes regarding it. The Android OS is supposed to handle the closing of applications on it's own, we shouldn't interfere with it. So,even going for `System.exit()` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finish all the activity first and before finishing last activity just add the below line

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

which will kill the process which is started for that application.

Comment: Read the android documentations. It says : _Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's packages/application and any additional processes created by that app; packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's processes._

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` instead of this and you must exit the app from the main activity itself.
If you pressing Home button on any activity , it will start the same Activity next time.

Or add more detail in your question for better solution.